# Prisma connector not supporting lists of primitive types

Tags: next.js, prisma, mysql-connector

Iam getting this error :
error: Field "images" in model "Gigs" can't be a list. The current connector does not support lists of primitive types.
Iam using latest version of both prisma and MySQL which supports lists of primitive types but it is still showing me this error

I tried updating prisma and MySQL but nothing changed